Understanding ハッタリ in context
Lyrics for the first chorus of Overdose by なとり are as follows:

Overdose 君とふたり
やるせない日々
解像度の悪い夢を見たい
Overdose 君とふたり
甘いハッタリ
Don't stop it music, darling

I'm trying to understand the etymology and nuance of ハッタリ. Though transcribed in katakana here, it seems to be a native Japanese word also often written in hiragana.
E-J dictionaries were not useful; I just get "bluff" as a definition, but that is a very broad term in English. J-J dictionaries seem to indicate that this is originally a -tari form of 張る, or perhaps 貼る, and describe a particular meaning along the lines of an empty threat used for intimidation. That doesn't seem to make sense for the context of the song (it seems like it should mean the sort of deception that lovers or prospective lovers use against each other, to protect their egos or make themselves seem more attractive), and I also can't understand how such a meaning is reached from the original verbs.
Does ハッタリ have the same sort of broad applicability that "bluff" does in English? For example, could it refer to a) a promise one doesn't intend to keep; b) what Phoenix Wright does in court when he hasn't yet figured out how to connect his narrative to the evidence (in the localized version; I don't know how it's rendered originally); c) a poker bet made with a weak hand to induce a fold? Would it be reasonable to use a word like "lie" or "deception" instead in a translation here?
And what has bluffing got to do with spreading out and covering something, or attaching?

[1][ニ]③ here might answer your last question.

About your last question, はる (bearing in mind that the kanji spellings are just specific nuances of this same underlying Japonic root word) has a core sense of "to become or make taut, stretched, spread out".  The "glue down" and "cover" senses derive from the idea of spreading out something flat over an area.

@EiríkrÚtlendi I inferred as much, but I still don't really see how bluffing relates to that. The metaphor just doesn't resonate for me, I guess.

Bluffing is related to betting as one can see in usage c), isn't it? Or are you wondering how betting relates to the idea of spreading something?

@KarlKnechtel, consider the English expressions blowhard, to puff oneself up, big-headed, sticking one's chest out – all ideas of being outsized, of stretching one's accomplishments (and possibly others' credulity ). See also JA expression 胸を張る.

@aguijonazo the latter. But more importantly, I want to understand what exactly a "sweet bluff" might entail in the context of the song, which seems to describe lovers having difficulty being honest with each other in hard times.

Not sure what exactly what it means in that song, but it could be broadly understood as pretending to be capable of something (you know) you are not quite up to.

In the song, this person seems to be in despair, so ハッタリ in this context refers to an attempt to make himself look confident or big. It's roughly the same as 強がり here.
(As for the etymology, it has nothing to do with AたりBたり meaning "doing things like A and B". Although the etymology is discussed in this article, the meaning is far removed from the original verb's meaning, so you should remember it without worrying about the etymology.)
